# HTML text formatting and background on <textarea>

Tags: html, textarea

Using HTML, how can I format the text using the  tag and also specify the background color for the text area box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the below CSS code, you can change the background color

```
textarea {
    background-color: green; }
```

Or add a style tag to the text area

```
<textarea style="background-color:red;"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea style="background-color: blue; font-family:Verdana; font-size:14px; color:yellow;">
</textarea>
```

Change background and font.